# Wire Logger configuration behavior on Spring Reactor Netty

Tags: spring-boot, logging, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor-netty

While trying to configure Reactor Netty wiretap feature on a WebFlux client to see the generated requests (and more detailed response), I've ended up with the following **working** setup:

In a service bean:

```
private WebClient client = WebClient.builder()
        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(
             HttpClient.create().wiretap("webClientLogger", LogLevel.DEBUG, AdvancedByteBufFormat.TEXTUAL)
            ))
            .baseUrl("https://...")
            .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_NDJSON_VALUE)
            .codecs(codecs -> codecs.defaultCodecs().jackson2JsonDecoder(new Jackson2JsonDecoder(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.json().build(), 
                    new MimeType("application", "json"), new MimeType("application", "x-ndjson"))))
            .build();
```

and in `application.properties`:

```
logging.level.webClientLogger = DEBUG
```

My question is, why, given that both the `name` and the `level` of the logger seems to be already defined in the `#wiretap` method's signature, the above line in the `application.property` is still required (as commenting it out stops producing any log output).

Relevant [Reactor Netty documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/snapshot/reference/index.html#_wire_logger_2) seems to reference `reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient`, however adding `reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient=DEBUG`  to `application.properties` without it having the above mentioned line doesn't make any difference and still doesn't produce the log output.

As a note, I'm using Lombok with its respective annotation `@Slf4j` to materialize the logging behavior.

Comment: `reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClient` is used only in case `wiretap(true)` is used i.e. when you do not specify the logger. In your use case you specify your own logger `webClientLogger`

Comment: Hi Violeta.  Yes, I do specify my own logger `webClientLogger` and I do set its level to DEBUG in the first two parameters to the `wiretap` method on the web client, so my question is - why do I need to repeat myself by specifying the same info in `application.properties`?